# How this works: print(sum(int(x) for x in raw_input().split())) in Python

Tags: python

I am very new in Python, and I am really surprised at the following line of code.

```
print (sum(int(x) for x in raw_input().split()))
```

I cannot understand what is happening inside with my Java brain, especially the way x passed to int() from for loop.

Comment: That's almost plain english... Just read it.

Comment: Can you take a guess? Have you tried to do _anything_ to help yourself understand it? Maybe break it into pieces and figure out what each does individually?

Comment: @Josh Caswell I understand how it works and know how I can use it. The thing I want to know is the concept (somewhat theoretical) of the way x passed to int() because it does not exist the languages I know, C++ and Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`raw_input().split()` returns an array for each line of input. `(int(x) for x in a)` is a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) which applies `int` to each line of input, converting it to an integer. The result of the generator expression is an array of integers; one for each line of input.

Finally `sum` takes the sum of all the elements in the array, and of course `print` will output the whole lot. So the result is code which produces the sum of all lines of input where each line is a number.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the concept of "generator expression"

Answer (score 3):

First, `raw_input().split()` reads a line which is then split into its whitespace-separated components. So a line like `1 3 2 5 7 3` becomes the list `['1', '3', '2', '5', '7', '3']`.

This list is used in a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) `int(x) for x in list_above`. This expression evaluates to a generator which transforms the elements of the list into their `int()` representations.

This generator is evaluated during the call of `sum()`, which adds up all the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break it down.

```
print (sum(int(x) for x in raw_input().split()))
```

Is also expressed as

```
sequence = raw_input().split()
conv = []
for i in sequence:
    conv.append(int(i))
print sum(conv)
```

Now we can combine this into one line using

```
[int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

But this is not lazy, So to make it lazy we simply replace the `[` with `(`

```
(int(x) for x in raw_input().split())
```

Now because this is an iterable object we can now pass this to `sum()`

And that is what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generator expression. As a very rough approximation you can read it like

```
a = []
for x in raw_input().split():
    a.append(int(x))
print sum(a)
```

but it is not building the intermediate list `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The innermost portion, `(int(x) for x in raw_input().split())` is a generator expression which works like this:

```
(and_evaluate_this for into,these,variables in unpack_this)
```

Now remove the words "for" and "in" leaving:

```
(and_evaluate_this     into,these,variables    unpack_this)
```

And read from **right to left**. A sequence of the evaluated expressions is generated by looping over these steps.

Answer (score 0):

with this `split()` you break the digits, so now you have a list.

you iterate in this list: `for x in "list"`

and you cast this x to int: `int(x)`

all of this in one line of code